# Can Ubuntu work with a Belkin N150 Wireless USB Adapter out of the box?

Tags: networking, wireless, drivers, usb

I don't have Wi-Fi on my motherboard, so I'll need Ubuntu to support a wireless N150 USB adapter to connect to the router. Can Ubuntu 15.04 support this out of the box (without a need for updating?)

I ask because it's not possible for me to connect to the internet to get drivers for it when I need it to connect to the internet in the first place, and it's not possible to move the motherboard and connect directly to the modem in my house because I have no control over it and it's just impossible.

So, to ask again, can ANY Ubuntu work natively with a Belkin N15 Wireless Adapter USB hub?

I don't care which version it is, so long as it's at least 13.04.

To be exact, it has to "just work." 12.04 doesn't seem to be able to do this. Any that can for sure?

This is the exact model: F7D1101 v1.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lsusb` terminal command with the adapter connected. Same model can have various chips inside.

Comment: Not possible ... haven't even used a distro yet.